# Concatenating the values of an object's properties returns NaN (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have an object with multiple properties, each property has a value that is a string. When I try to concatenate the values of each property, it returns NaN.

```
var urlProps = {
   searchTerm: "searchSTUFF",
   baseURL: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=1&exlimit=10&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=%20&generator=search&gsrsearch=",
   tailURL: "&rawcontinue=&callback=?",
   finalURL: this.baseURL + this.searchTerm + this.tailURL
}

console.log(urlProps.finalURL);
//NaN
```

What am I doing wrong here, or what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the point where you're trying to concatenate the values the object has not yet been created.
Also `this` would not represent the object in any case. You'd use this in a constructor or an object method.
To get the result you want you'll have to do this.

```
var urlProps = {
   searchTerm: "searchSTUFF",
   baseURL: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=1&exlimit=10&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=%20&generator=search&gsrsearch=",
   tailURL: "&rawcontinue=&callback=?",
   finalURL: this.baseURL + this.searchTerm + this.tailURL
}
urlProps.finalURL = urlProps.baseURL + urlProps.searchTerm + urlProps.tailURL;
```

Comment: Ahh, I had no idea that you couldn't reference previous properties in object literals. This is really great to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using function

```
var urlProps = {
   searchTerm: "searchSTUFF",
   baseURL: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=1&exlimit=10&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=%20&generator=search&gsrsearch=",
   tailURL: "&rawcontinue=&callback=?",
   finalURL: function() { return this.baseURL + this.searchTerm + this.tailURL; }
}

console.log(urlProps.finalURL());
//https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&e…=&titles=%20&generator=search&gsrsearch=searchSTUFF&rawcontinue=&callback=?
```

Answer (score 1):

The JS engine cannot find `this.baseUrl` or `this.searchTerm` or `this.tailUrl` when trying to build `finalUrl` because the object you're building doesn't 'exist' for the purposes of reference until it the engine finishes building it (at the `}`).

To make this work, you need to make sure the object has finished being built before trying to refer to it:

```
var urlProps = {
   searchTerm: "searchSTUFF",
   baseURL: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=1&exlimit=10&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=%20&generator=search&gsrsearch=",
   tailURL: "&rawcontinue=&callback=?"
}

// here it can find it...
urlProps.finalURL =  urlProps.baseURL + urlProps.searchTerm + urlProps.tailURL;
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.baseURL`, `this.searchTerm` and `this.tailURL` are all `undefined` at that point in the object literal. You have to generate the final URL in a separate statement:

```
var urlProps = {
   searchTerm: "searchSTUFF",
   baseURL: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exsentences=1&exlimit=10&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=%20&generator=search&gsrsearch=",
   tailURL: "&rawcontinue=&callback=?"
};
urlProps.finalURL = urlProps.baseURL + urlProps.searchTerm + urlProps.tailURL;
```

The object only exists after the statement with the object literal and within the object literal `this` points to the `window` object (or whatever the context is), not to the object to be created.